# How to save code snippets in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Please suggest how to add this below query to DB. I need to save the code in code_snippet property.

```
CREATE(a1:DOM { 
name:'render',
officialLink:'http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children.toarray',
blogLink:'NA',
codeSnippet:'ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('MyComponent'));'})
```

Comment: have you considered base64 encoding it?

Comment: Sorry @David im unaware of base64 encoding.

Comment: I require to add the above code snippet property to my graph db in neo4j

Comment: I expect that the way your question is currently phrased it will likely go unanswered.  You have asked for a solution but you have not adequately described the problem space nor have you demonstrated what attempts you have made to solve the problem yourself. I would suggest you review one or all of: [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Stack Overflow Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).